# Cannot add fields before name widget - magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, template

I'm trying to add a field in the "new customer" form, so i would like to put something into customer_account_create.xml layout, precisely in the block

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register" template="form/register.phtml">
```

so, after

```
<container name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="customer-form-before"/>
```

but before the "name widget" created runtime as a block in register.phtml

```
<legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Personal Information') ?></span></legend><br>
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name')->setObject($block->getFormData())->setForceUseCustomerAttributes(true)->toHtml() ?>
```

but i can't manage to do it

i tried on my custom customer_account_create.xml, under my modules view/frontend/layout directory, putting

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="smtn-be4-name"  as="before-name" template="Vendor_Module::customTemplate.phtml" after="form_fields_before"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

but it doesnt appear (lets say i created customTemplate.phtml under my module's view/frontend/templates directory, which prints something)

any ideas/help?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

okay, there's no way to refer a block which is created runtime like the widgets for customer data (name etc .) this is -quite obviously- because widgets are rendered AFTER the blocks defined in the layout xml